# Why scrapy not iterating over all the links on the page even the xpaths are correct?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

This code works perfectly fine when I pass `extract()[0]` or `extract()` - it gives me output for the first link it parsed.I am not able to understand why its doing so,bcs when I was crawling Other websites with this code it was perfectly fine.

With this website its scraping only the first link.If I change `extract()[1]` then it will give me second link and so on .Why its not working automatically in for loop?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


class CompItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    data = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()



class criticspider(BaseSpider):
    name = "mmt_mouth"
    allowed_domains = ["mouthshut.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mouthshut.com/websites/makemytripcom-reviews-925031929"]
    # rules = (
        # Rule(
            # SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("search=make-my-trip&page=1/+",)),
            # callback="parse",
            # follow=True),
    # )

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//div[@id="allreviews"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = CompItem()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('.//li[@class="profile"]/div/a/span/text()').extract()[0]
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="reviewtitle fl"]/strong/a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['date'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="reviewrate"]//span[@class="datetime"]/span/span/span/text()').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="reviewtitle fl"]/strong/a/@href').extract()[0]
            if item['link']:
                if 'http://' not in item['link']:
                    item['link'] = urljoin(response.url, item['link'])
                yield scrapy.Request(item['link'],
                                    meta={'item': item},
                                    callback=self.anchor_page)

            items.append(item)

    def anchor_page(self, response):
        old_item = response.request.meta['item']

        old_item['data'] = response.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="description"]/p/text()').extract()
        yield old_item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your for loop has nothing to loop on the given website. Change your statement

```
sites = response.xpath('//div[@id="allreviews"]')
```

to

```
sites = response.xpath('//div[@id="allreviews"]/ul/li')
```

Then your for loop can loop over the list elements.

Comment: Thank you sir :) so much,so its with the xpath.It should be detailed as possible so that for loop iterates over it